# identifier "puts" is undefined C/C++(20) [3,5] error

Tags: c

I am 16 pages into the book "C All-in-one Desk Reference for Dummies. I am using Visual Studio Code as my editor and MinGW as my compiler. I have been prompted to write and compile the code:

```
int main() 
{
    puts("Greetings, human!");
    return(0);
}
```

I have compiled it. Two things arrived from this. The first issue arrived in the terminal:

```
dumb.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     puts("Greetings, human!");
     ^~~~
```

The second arrived on the (problems) tab next to output, it gives me a notification that says, `"identifier "puts" is undefined    C/C++(20) [3,5]".`

I am afraid to move forward because I don't want to mess anything up.

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` should be the first line in the `.c` file.

Comment: Are you compiling this as C or C++?

Comment: see I would have never, ever, have guessed to put that because the book simply has not taught me that yet... that's concerning to me as a beginner because this book is supposed to be a follow-along type of book from my understanding...

Comment: im compiling this as C @tadman

Comment: @MattTriano The functions at your disposal, the headers required for each, their defined behaviors, etc. [can be found here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). For example, [`puts`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts).

Comment: Is it an old book? Prior to 1999 the header was optional

Comment: `int main()` is also wrong for modern C.  It is likely to work anyway, but it should be `int main(void)`.  Two such issues in a three-line program suggests that this is not a good book to be learning from.

Answer (score 2):

Just include the `#include<stdio.h>` on the first line because the `gets()` and `puts()` are declared in the header file `stdio.h`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    puts("Greetings, human!");
    return(0);
}
```

**Note - Even if gets() is declared in <stdio.h>, you should never use it. It was removed from Standard C for good reason. It cannot be used safely**

Comment: Even if `gets()` is declared in `<stdio.h>`, you should never use it.  It was removed from Standard C for good reason.  It cannot be used safely.